# Introducing periodic jitter to a clock

Tags: noise, phase

This question is about the ideal digital clock. Lets consider an ideal clock with 0 raise time and 0 fall time i.e. perfect square wave. As shown in the diagram below. Let the original clock period be T

[image: Square clock with period T]

Now suppose we want to introduce jitter which is periodic in nature. Each clock edge will move wrt previous edge aand it will not have constant time period. The time period itself will be a function of time. Let $\delta_n$ be the shift to be given (it can be both +ve or -ve) to each clock.

$\delta_n = A_j \cos(2\pi f_j t)$

Where
$A_j$ is the amplitude of the jitter
$f_j$ is the frequency of the jitter as shown in diagram below

[image: Phase Error with clock]

MTIE is the Maximum time interval error defined as is the maximum error committed by a clock under test in measuring a time interval for a given period of time.

Suppose we want the MTIE to be $X \mu sec$ and the jitter to have frequency of $f_j$. What should be the function of $\delta_n$ ?

$T + \delta_n$ is the period of each clock pulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_j = x/2 \space \mu s$ will guarantee $MTIE \le x \space \mu s$ since MTIE is the peak to peak time error, and $A_j$ is the peak time error. This will reduce as a first order (-20 dB/decade) high pass response when frequency $f_j$ is below the reciprocal of the observation time $\tau$ seconds with a -6 dB cutoff frequency of $1/(2\pi \tau)$ Hz.

To explain MTIE, I will first explain **Time Error (TE)** and then **Time Interval Error (TIE)** and from that finally **Maximum Time Interval Error (MTIE)**:

For a given clock of frequency $\nu$:

**Time Error (TE)** is the error in time at any instant (measured at time $t$) between the clock and a "perfect" reference clock.  Since the OP has shown a plot of phase error, this is related to phase error according to:

$$TE(t) = \frac{\phi_e(t)}{2\pi \nu} \tag{1} \label{1}$$

Where:

$\nu$ is the clock frequency in Hz. 
$\phi_e(t)$ is the phase error in radians as a function of time. 
$TE(t)$ is the resulting time error in seconds as a function of time.

Equation \ref{1} is intuitively derived: the reciprocal of the clock frequency $\nu$ is the time duration to complete one clock cycle. $\phi/(2\pi)$ is the fraction of a cycle for the given phase error $\phi$, so we are simply converting phase as a fraction of a cycle to time in seconds.

Note here that $TE(t)$ is a continuous function of time applicable to a sinusoidal clock where instantaneous phase can be measured at any time. For a digital clock with infinitely fast edges, we can only measure time error at the clock edges, so becomes a discrete function, and in the OP's case sampled at the rising edges of the clock (so at the clock rate itself). It helps to understand both contexts, so I will introduce more generally with continuous time functions and then show the effect of sampling.

For a perfect clock, $TE(t)=0$.

We can relate this to the OP's jitter equation under condition of sinusoidal phase error which I will re-write in continuous form as:

$$\delta(t) = TE(t) = A \cos(2\pi f_j t)$$

This is a sinusoidal time error in units of seconds, but we can easily convert this back to a phase error using equation \ref{1} by as $\phi_e(t)= 2\pi \nu \delta(t)$. When referring to a clock at a single frequency, time error and phase error are the same function just using different units, not unlike converting meters to feet except our conversion rate is set by the frequency of the clock.

*(Note for those more familiar with phase noise and jitter: This is what would occur when our clock has local interference from another clock or pure tone at a different frequency which could induce both sinusoidal amplitude and phase. However it is more typical for our jitter to be limited by non-stationary phase noise which has a power spectral density as a continuous function in frequency, increasing in power as the frequency decreases. This example function by the OP can be interpreted as isolating one slice at a given frequency offset of that typical broader band phase noise process.)*

I plot an example $TE(t)$ below, along with vertical dashed lines indicating the locations of the rising edges assuming a clock frequency $\nu$ that is independent of the frequency of the sinusoidal time error. $\delta_n$ would be the value for $TE(t)$ at these dashed line locations, and if we observed for infinite time we will ultimately sample every possible value for $\delta(t)$.

[image: Time Error]

The OP has loosely defined samples of this function given as $\delta_n$ consistent with the time error measured at the rising edges of the digital clock.

**Time Interval Error (TIE)** is the Time Error over an observation time interval $\tau$ starting at time $t$, so is both a function of $\tau$ and $t$:

$$TIE(\tau, t) = TE(t + \tau) - TE(t)$$

**Maximum Time Interval Error (MTIE)** is given over a certain observation interval $\tau$ and is the maximum peak to peak deviation of time error over the observation interval $\tau$ for any start of observation $t$:

$$MTIE(\tau, t) = [TE(\tau, t)]_{MAX} - [TE(\tau, t)]_{MIN}$$

Thus, given a time interval of observation $\tau$ and any start time $t$, the maximum time interval error is the maximum Time Error minus the minimum Time Error as measured over that observation time. $t$ is implied to be the usable life of the product; we provide this specification to ensure a maximum expected time error over any observation time as defined is met.

We can see as depicted in the above plot that if our observation time $\tau$ exceeds one cycle time of the phase noise $1/f_j$, and if the clock frequency was high enough, the peak to peak time error as sampled by the rising edges of the clock will be at or very close to $2A$ (if sampled high enough and long enough to capture the peaks). What is interesting to note is the "high-pass" effect for lower frequency phase error components with frequencies below the cut-off of $1/\tau$, and the comb response (null to peak) for frequency components above that related to the exact relationships between the clock frequency and frequency of the phase noise for any given observation time.

For a sinusoidal clock where we can measure time error at any $t$, observing for finite observation intervals is a high pass process with a corner frequency of $1/\tau$ radians/sec consistent with the difference of a function over a finite time duration (which is exactly what time error is).  The actual frequency response is a comb cyclically going from null to peak, forming a first order high pass starting at DC and then cyclically going though nulls at the frequency harmonics of $1/\tau$.  I show this from the frequency response $H(j\omega)$ derived from the Laplace Transform for a continuous-time difference equation below, where we see how a first order high-pass frequency response results by observing the frequency response of the difference equation on a log log plot:

$$ TE(s) H(s) = \mathscr{L}\{TE(t+\tau) - TE(t)\} = TE(s)e^{j\tau s} - TE(S) = TE(s)( e^{j\tau s} - 1)$$

$$H(j\omega) = e^{j\omega\tau} - 1$$

Below shows an example plot of this for $\tau = 0.001$, resulting in a high-pass -6 dB cutoff frequency of 1000 radians/sec.

[image: Frequency Response]

This is a plot of the frequency response for a TIE measurement specifically, not MTIE (TIE is the instantaneous error, while MTIE is the peak to peak TIE over an observation interval). Note that for observation times $\tau$ less than a quarter cycle time of a sinusoidal phase noise $1/f_j$, and assuming for now a much higher clock rate, the worst case MTIE would equal the TIE, and so as the frequency of the phase noise continued to get lower (cycle time get longer relative to observation), the MTIE would reduce consistent with the high pass effect I show above.  For higher frequencies that are still significantly lower than the clock frequency, a given frequency for time error may be in one of the nulls of the frequency response given above causing the measured TIE to be 0 (this occurs whenever the sinusoidal phase error is an integer multiple of the observation time since $TE(t) = TE(t+\tau)$ always in this case), however the maximum and minimum over that interval will still result in measuring the maximum $MTIE$ consistent with being $2A$.

Under conditions of sampling, an exact result can be obtained using z transforms instead of Laplace and will result in a similar high pass response for all sinusoidal phase noise components that are both below Nyquist and with frequencies below the reciprocal of the observation time in samples $\tau_n$. Aliasing considerations are used to further detail the effect of higher frequency components above Nyquist. For most practical applications the continuous time models provided here would be sufficient and adequate for defining maximum MTIE given distributed phase noise sources that are independent of the frequency of the clock.